# What is the best way to add server variables (PHP) in to the Backbone.model using require.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm not sure what is the elegant way to pass server variables in to my Model.

For example, i have an id of user that has to be implemented on my Model. But seems like Backbone with require are not able to do that.

My two options are:

1. Get a json file with Ajax.
2. Add the variable on my index.php as a global.

Someone know if exists a other way. Native on the clases?

---

Trying to make work the example of backbonetutorials. I am not able to throw a callback when the method fetch().

```
$(document).ready(function() {



var Timer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'timeserver/',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
var timer = new Timer({id:1});
timer.fetch({
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success')
   },
   fail: function(model, response) {
       alert('fail');
   },
   sync: function(data) {
        alert('sync')
   }
});

});
```

The ajax request it has been threw. But does not work at all. Because any alert its dispatched.
[image: The ajax request it has been throwed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot: '/user',
      defaults: {
          name: '',
          email: ''
      }
});
// Here we have set the `id` of the model
var user = new Usermodel({id: 1});

// The fetch below will perform GET /user/1
// The server should return the id, name and email from the database
user.fetch({
    success: function (user) {
        console.log(user);
    }
})
```

The server  will reply with a json object then you can leave the rendering part for your backbone. Based on a template for the user.

You may also want to check these out: http://backbonetutorials.com/